# Centrar scrollspy bootstrap

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3, scroll

No consigo centrar el scrollspy ni con el `offset` ni añadiendo `padding` ni nada siempre me queda por debajo un trozo amarillo y lo quiero justo donde empieza lo amarillo. ¿Alguna posible solución?

Éste es mi código:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'webfontregular';
  src: url("../fonts/waterlily-webfont.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/waterlily-webfont.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal; 
}

body {
  position: relative !important;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

html {
  font-size: 15px; 
}


/*Estilos bloque bienvenidos*/
.bienvenidos {
  background: rgba(181,167,220,1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(181,167,220,1) 0%, rgba(127,111,176,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(181,167,220,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(127,111,176,1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(181,167,220,1) 0%, rgba(127,111,176,1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(181,167,220,1) 0%, rgba(127,111,176,1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(181,167,220,1) 0%, rgba(127,111,176,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(181,167,220,1) 0%, rgba(127,111,176,1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#b5a7dc', endColorstr='#7f6fb0', GradientType=0 );
  overflow: hidden; }

.logobrand {
  width: 35px; }

.boton3rayas {
  margin-top: 0.3rem; }

.navbar-fixed-top {
  background: #b5a7dc; }

.navbar-light .navbar-brand {
  color: #fdfb8e;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  text-transform: uppercase; }

.navbar-toggler {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  color: #fdfb8e; }

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #fdfb8e;
  text-align: center; }

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  background: #8a2be2; }

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: #fdfb8e; }

#menuprincipal {
  clear: both; }

.texto-bienvenido {
  color: yellow;
  margin-top: 7rem;
  font-family: "webfontregular", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem; }

.bienvenido2 p {
  color: black; }

.imaginarq {
  font-size: 4rem; }

.bienvenido2 {
  color: yellow; }

/*Estilos bloque quehacemos*/
.quehacemos {
  background: rgba(253,251,142,1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(253,251,142,1) 0%, rgba(214,210,102,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(253,251,142,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(214,210,102,1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(253,251,142,1) 0%, rgba(214,210,102,1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(253,251,142,1) 0%, rgba(214,210,102,1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(253,251,142,1) 0%, rgba(214,210,102,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(253,251,142,1) 0%, rgba(214,210,102,1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fdfb8e', endColorstr='#d6d266', GradientType=0 );
}

.quehacemos h4 {
  font-weight: bolder; }

.btn-outline-secondary {
  color: rgba(253,251,142,1);
  background-image: none;
  background-color: rgba(127,111,176,1);
  border-color: rgba(253,251,142,1);
}

.quehacemos .fa {
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: rgba(127,111,176,1);}

/*Estilos quienes somos*/
.quienes {
  background: rgba(181,167,220,1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(181,167,220,1) 0%, rgba(127,111,176,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(181,167,220,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(127,111,176,1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(181,167,220,1) 0%, rgba(127,111,176,1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(181,167,220,1) 0%, rgba(127,111,176,1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(181,167,220,1) 0%, rgba(127,111,176,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(181,167,220,1) 0%, rgba(127,111,176,1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#b5a7dc', endColorstr='#7f6fb0', GradientType=0 );
}

.quienes h4 {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.conchi {
  border-radius: 50%; 
}

.cabeza {

  border-radius: 50%; }

.agustin {

  border-radius: 50%; }

.somosbotones {
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  color: rgba(253,251,142,1);
}

/* Estilos ultimos trabajos*/
.trabajos {
  background: rgba(253,251,142,1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(253,251,142,1) 0%, rgba(214,210,102,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(253,251,142,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(214,210,102,1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(253,251,142,1) 0%, rgba(214,210,102,1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(253,251,142,1) 0%, rgba(214,210,102,1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(253,251,142,1) 0%, rgba(214,210,102,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(253,251,142,1) 0%, rgba(214,210,102,1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fdfb8e', endColorstr='#d6d266', GradientType=0 );
}

.trabajos h4 {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.card {
  background-color: #b5a7dc;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}
.card img{
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s;
  transition: all 0.6s;
  width: 100%;
}

.card:hover img {
  transform : scale(1.1);
  -moz-transform : scale(1.1);      /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transform : scale(1.1);   /* Chrome - Safari */
  -o-transform : scale(1.1);        /* Opera */
}



.card-img-top {
  border-style: groove;
}
.card h4 {
  color: #fdfb8e;
}

/* Estilos clientes*/

.clientes {
  background: rgba(181,167,220,1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(181,167,220,1) 0%, rgba(127,111,176,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(181,167,220,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(127,111,176,1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(181,167,220,1) 0%, rgba(127,111,176,1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(181,167,220,1) 0%, rgba(127,111,176,1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(181,167,220,1) 0%, rgba(127,111,176,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(181,167,220,1) 0%, rgba(127,111,176,1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#b5a7dc', endColorstr='#7f6fb0', GradientType=0 );
}

.clientes h4 {
  font-weight: bolder;
}
.h6cliente {
  text-align: right;
}

.contacto {
  background: rgba(253,251,142,1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(253,251,142,1) 0%, rgba(214,210,102,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(253,251,142,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(214,210,102,1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(253,251,142,1) 0%, rgba(214,210,102,1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(253,251,142,1) 0%, rgba(214,210,102,1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(253,251,142,1) 0%, rgba(214,210,102,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(253,251,142,1) 0%, rgba(214,210,102,1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fdfb8e', endColorstr='#d6d266', GradientType=0 );   
}

.contacto h4 {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

/*Estilos footer*/
.footer {
  background: rgba(181,167,220,1); }

.footer .fa {
  font-size: 35px; }


/*Estilos Media Query*/
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #menuprincipal {
    clear: inherit; } }
/*# sourceMappingURL=estilos.css.map */

/*# sourceMappingURL=estilos.css.map */
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.7/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!-- Cabecera Bar Nav -->
<section class="bienvenidos">
  <header class="encabezado">
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-fixed-top" id="navbarscroll">
        <div class="container">
          <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-md-up pull-xs-right boton3rayas" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menuprincipal">
            ☰
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" class="logobrand img-fluid"></a>
          <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-sm pull-md-right" id="menuprincipal">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#quehacemos">¿QUIÉNES SOMOS?</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">¿QUÉ HACEMOS?</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">¿CLIENTES?</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTACTO</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">PORTFOLIO</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="texto-bienvenido text-xs-center">
      <h3 class="imaginarq">IMAGINARQ</h3>
      <h2 class="h1">Gestion Cultural</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="bienvenido2 text-xs-center m-t-1">
      <p>Empresa joven, renovadora, original, dinamica, e innovadora en el sector cultural.</p>
      <p>Somos IMAGINARQ, somos "Los Niños de la Tablet"</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>




<!-- Que Hacemos-->  
<section id="quehacemos" class="quehacemos p-y-2 text-xs-center">
  <div class="container">
    <h4 class="h4">¿QUÉ HACEMOS?</h4>
    <div class="row m-t-2">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3">
        <i class="fa fa-tablet img-fluid m-x-auto m-b-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <h4 class="h4">TURISMO TECNOLOGICO Y CIENTIFICO</h4>
        <p>¿Te apetecería descubrir tesoros ocultos, transportarte al pasado y sentirte como un arqueólogo gracias a las nuevas tecnologías?.</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary m-b-2">Saber más</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o img-fluid m-x-auto m-b-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <h4 class="h4">DIDÁCTICA DEL PATRIMONIO</h4>
        <p>Renovamos el concepto de taller pedagógico y de la visita cultural incluyendo en nuestras propuestas escolares el uso de tablets digitales para fomentar un uso didáctico y responsable de las nuevas tecnologías entre l@s alumn@s.</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary m-b-2">Saber más</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3">
        <i class="fa fa-eye img-fluid m-x-auto m-b-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <h4 class="h4">PROYECTOS CULTURALES</h4>
        <p>Una de nuestras señas de identidad es complementar cualquier tipo de actividad con la cultura, dotándole así de un componente enriquecedor para este tipo de actos.</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary m-b-2">Saber más</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3">
        <i class="fa fa-search img-fluid m-x-auto m-b-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <h4 class="h4">ARQUEOLOGÍA</h4>
        <p>Nos avalan más de 10 años en el mundo de la arqueología lo que nos hace profundos conocedores de la realidad del trabajo arqueológico y de su gestión.</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary m-b-2">Saber más</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

En esta a ver si se entiende mejor, la barra de navegacion me tapa justo el donde tiene ke comenzar el desplazamiento del scroll. quiero que la barra quede mas arriba y no me tape el encabezado.

[image: foto ejemplo]

Comment: Por favor, limpia el código hasta quedarte sólo con la parte que falla en lugar de con toda la página (de ese modo será más fácil ayudar). También explica mejor el problema, tal y como está puesto ahora, no entiendo qué es lo que falla ni qué es lo que quieres hacer, que son esenciales para poder ayudarte.

Comment: vale he dejado solo el trozo y el css completo por si acaso, el problema es que no consigo que se me centre el scrollspy siempre me queda pordebajo, ni consiguo centralo ni con margin ni con padding ni nada x el estilo.

Comment: que quieres centrar no entiendo]?

Comment: centrar no es exactamente como se dice, quiero que se me mueva al darle el botón a donde empieza si le doy a servicios que se me desplaza a servicios pero que no se me quede por debajo del titulo servicios.

Comment: Creo que uno de los problemas que estamos teniendo (al menos yo) es que estás hablando de "scrollspy", pero no hay nada en el código que se llame de ese modo, lo que confunde un poco. ¿Qués es el scrollspy?¿por debajo de qué queda?¿Podrías añadir una imagen del error y de cómo debería verse en realidad?

Comment: @alfonsoPerez, siendo asi, vuelve a subir todo el codigo

Comment: No es posible entender qué es realmente lo que necesitas, puedes ser más especifico por favor.

Comment: el scrollspy es una funcion de bootstrap, el problema que creo que me ocurre es que tengo que tener el body en position: relative, y ese efecto en body no se esta produciendo algo lo esta bloqueando.

Comment: Saludos hermano, por curiosidad ¿lograste hacerlo funcionar?